# Test login on ios app with xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

I want to test if the connection settings are properly once the user has completed all fields. I already get connected, but I would like a condition if the username or password are incorrect.

My MainViewController.m

```
 NSString* host = @"http://www.example.com";
        NSString* complement = @"/account/login";



        NSString* user_name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identifiant"];
        NSString* password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Password"];
        //Add URL + Folder
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", host, complement];


        //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


        //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        //Add some informations POST
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_name=%@&password=%@&submit=submit", user_name, password];;


        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];



        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
             if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) [_loadscreen loadRequest:request];
             else if (error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];
```

If the password or Id is incorrect, I want to display an error, actually, when It's incorrect, it's display the login page on the webview, but I don't want display the login web page.

Comment: What are you getting in response and in error ?

Comment: Currently nothing is displaying, no error, no respond. I feel that the app receives a positive response and suddenly the webview load, but once loaded it redirects me to the login page because the identifiers are not correct

Answer (score 1):

why you are doing this way, why you are using 'POST' method you are not posting something to server page. you just need to implement Json Parsing thats it try this :

you just need to do some corrections at you php code end. tell them to return success = "0" when userId & password do not match and if they match return you "1". :

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSString *jsonUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/pagename.php?username=%@&password=%@",emailText.Text,passwordText.Text];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSMutableArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",result);

NSString *stringData = [result valueForKey:@"success"];
if ([stringData isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"wrong credentials" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
} else {
 //perform anything you want to perform
}
```

Comment: no no, this code is written in XCode. when you press submit button after filling up username and password. paste this code under that function. and ask  you php guy to take car at php end.

Comment: When I try the code, I have this log : (null) , it's the error log, and i'm not logged

Comment: And on my webserver, php check if it's a post submit `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments in the block

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
             if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) 
             {
               [_loadscreen loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<new page url>"]]];
               // Over here you are loading the same request object, which contains older request URL in it.
               // There should be new URL request which lead the user to next page URL.   
             }
             else if (error != nil) 
             {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             }
         }];
```

Comment: How to load different url so ?

Comment: I'm always redirect to my login page :/

Comment: Then its obvious that after successful login it will navigate again to login page only